# How to cluster points based on network traveling time to a common location?

Tags: qgis, clustering, network-analysis

I have a set of points that I need to divide into N different clusters. I know how to do this with the arithmetic distance, but in this example I need to cluster them based on the network traveling time.

One solution that accomplishes what I want would be to cluster the points in such a way that the total travel time to any N given points on the map is as low as possible. If the points could be weighed differently that would be even better. Is there any tool that allows for this? Preferably for QGIS.

The "real-life" application is to locate where N number of terminals should ideally be located given the set of points.